# How to close a trade after a certain time if a position is in loss | MQL4

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

I trade on **`1H`** & **`4H`** cycles, & I'm trying to implement coding that closes a position if it is in a loss & by the time it is a half way through the trade cycle ( `PERIOD_CURRENT` ).

**Trade Cycle `4H` = 4 `[hr]` = 240 `[min]` = 14,400 `[s]`**

A trade cycle is `4H`, so I want to be able to automatically close a position if a trade is in loss 2 hours after the trade was initially opened.

Based on the time, being in seconds since 1/1/1970, I've compared the **`TimeCurrent()`** with the **`OrderOpenTime()`** + the **`4H`** in seconds, but divided this by two to get the time after two hours.

This however isn't working - I've added the code below.

If anyone can shed any light on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

**Example**

```
OrderStartTime = 14,000,000

OrderCloseTime = 14,000,000 + 60 minutes * 240 minutes = 14,014,400 <<<<<
```

**Close half way through
 if trade is in loss at time** `= 14,000,000 + (60 * 240*0.5) = 140,007,200`

```
for ( int earlcloses = OrdersTotal() - 1; earlcloses >= 0; earlcloses-- )
{
    if (                        OrderSelect( earlcloses, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES ) )
         if (                   OrderType()                               == OP_SELL )
               if (             OrderMagicNumber()                        == Period() )
                     if (       OrderOpenTime() + ( 60 * Period() * 0.5 ) <= TimeCurrent() )
                           if ( OrderOpenPrice()                          <  Bid )
                           { // |||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
                             /* --serially-nested-if()-s CODEBLOCK-{}-START--- */

                                earlcloses = OrderClose( OrderTicket(),
                                                         LotSize,
                                                         MarketInfo( sym, MODE_BID )
                                                       + MarketInfo( sym, MODE_SPREAD )
                                                       * MarketInfo( sym, MODE_POINT ),
                                                         300,
                                                         clrNONE
                                                         );

                             /* ------------------------ CODEBLOCK-{}-FINISH--- */
                           } // ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
    if ( earlcloses == true )
    {    Sleep( 60000 );
         int  earlyclosesel =  OrdersHistoryTotal()-1;
         bool earlySelect   =  OrderSelect( earlyclosesel, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY );
         if ( earlySelect   == true )
         {
              int earlTicket = OrderTicket();
              SendMail( "Notification of early position closure", "Trade #" + IntegerToString( earlTicket, 0 ) + "has been closed at" + DoubleToStr( OrderClosePrice(), 5 ) + "due to timeout" );
         }
         else if ( earlySelect == false )
              {
                   Print( "EarlyClose failed with error #", GetLastError() );
              }
    }
 }
```

Comment: `Trade Cycle = 4 Hours = 240 seconds` - may be minutes obviously?

Comment: Yes, sorry & corrected

Comment: `60 minutes * 240minutes ` again, what is it, squared minutes? If you want to use dimensions, than it will something like `60 sec/min * 240 min = 14400 sec`

Comment: The MQL platform measures time in seconds, so if the order open time is 14,000,000 seconds since 1/1/1970 so closing the position will be at 14,014,400 seconds since 1/1/1970. Half way will be 14,007,200 seconds since 1/1/1970 so 60 * 240 = 14,400. No early closes though so I'm thinking the brackets may be the issue perhaps

Answer (score 0):

### `MQL4` Language constructors' syntax should be well understood:

As repaired above, the code is doing a single command `earlcloses = OrderClose(...);` if and only if all serially nested `if()`-conditions were met.

Right after that ( only conditionally executed `CODEBLOCK-{}` ),
there is a next line, which is on the contrary evaluated in each `for(){...}` loop round, except the last one:

```
if ( earlcloses == true )
```

This **`if()`**-condition evaluates to True in all cases, except in the last `for(){...}` loop round, because until that last one, the `for(){...}` loop--control variable declared as

```
for( int earlcloses =  OrdersTotal() - 1; // .SET  initial value
         earlcloses >= 0;                 // .TEST before a loop-execution starts
         earlcloses--                     // .UPD  after  a loop-execution
         ){...}
```

This means, your code arrives at the `( earlcloses == true )` test always with a value `> False`, which yields the **`True`** output from the `if(...)` test and the following `{...}` code will be executed ( except the very last loop of the for(), where the `earlcloses == 0`, thus yielding the `if()`-test **`False`**, as noted above.

---

### `OrderClose()` shall obey the XTO-rules, ref. other your Questions

Submitting a server-side executed instructions, be sure to have the prices setup correctly. Read about **`RefreshRates()`** instead of processing results from `MarketInfo()` and **as has been repeated several times in your previous questions, always `NormalizeDouble()`**.

---

### Robust `MQL4` code never relies on db.Pool `ORDER_BY_POS`:

Rather work with `OrderTicket()` db.Pool-***DMA***-mode. As listed in your code, implicit position-based assumptions lead to cases, when there is none record in the `HISTORY`-part of the db.Pool and a blind attempt to `OrderSelect( ...,  MODE_HISTORY )` will fail.

---

### Time Comparisons should be correct:

```
( OrderOpenTime() + 0.5 * PeriodSeconds( PERIOD_CURRENT ) <= TimeCurrent() )
```

---

### The worst error
in the concept of the `MQL4` code above
is in an intervening assignment,
damaging the logic of a `for(){...}`-loop-control variable

This if obvious from:

```
for ( int earlcloses = OrdersTotal() - 1; earlcloses >= 0; earlcloses-- )
{   if ( ...
          ..
           .
            {                      earlcloses = OrderClose( OrderTicket(), ... );
            }
    ...
}
```

**The very first `OrderClose()` call kills the whole `for(){...}` logic** leaving **`{none|one}`**-last loop via it's intervening assignment of a value of `{ 0 | 1 }` into the loop-control variable.

---

### Epilogue:

Once you have posted in one of your last four questions a comment, that you feel disgusted by not having the code running as you wish, because otherwise, you have a profitable strategy, it seems double the reasonable to hire a professional to have the algorithmisation done for you correct and robust. It would yield you the strategy RTO much faster, than correcting individual code-snippets.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the explanation & fair comment as well :)

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry I haven't voted, I'm still learning my way around the site. I'm a newbie here :) I want to ask for more detail but I'm not sure where the line is between asking formore questions & getting people to code for me, which I know isn't what this site is about.

Comment: A good practice & a well received attitude is to post both a code, with a reasonable context of use, together with error-logs ( journalled Print() self-diagnostics messages ) and PrintScreens, to show both your interest in solving the blocking trouble ( try to check an MCVE-principle on StackOverflow Do's and Dont's ) and also your own inputs of what have you tried so far for problem-isolation and issue-resolution. I know it is not so easy in some complex cases, where code-base spans more than 200.000 SLOCs, but in MQL4 this could be quite ok to describe the intention and show results.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion. Please read the comments:

```
for ( int orderIndex = OrdersTotal() - 1; orderIndex >= 0; orderIndex-- ) {
    //Note: You are closing ALL orders regardless of Symbol() of the current chart!!
    if (                        OrderSelect( orderIndex, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES ) )
         if (                   OrderType()                               == OP_SELL )
               if (             OrderMagicNumber()                        == Period() )
                     if (       (TimeCurrent()-OrderOpenTime())           >= (60*Period()/2) )
                           if ( (              OrderProfit()     // P&L
                                             + OrderCommission() // needs to factor in Commission
                                             + OrderSwap()       // needs to factor in all Swaps
                                               )                          <  0.0 ) {
                             // --------------------------------------------------
                                RefreshRates();                  // VERY IMPORTANT
                             // --------------------------------------------------                                    
                                int  closedTicket = OrderTicket();
                                if (  OrderClose( closedTicket,
                                                  OrderLots(),
                                                  MarketInfo( Symbol(), MODE_ASK ),   //You are closing a SELL trade, should use ASK price.
                                                  300, clrNONE ) ) {
                                      SendMail( "Notification of early position closure",
                                                "Trade #" + IntegerToString( closedTicket, 0 )
                                              + " has been closed at " + DoubleToStr( MarketInfo( Symbol(), MODE_ASK), 5 ) + " due to timeout."
                                                );
                                }
                                else {
                                      Print( "EarlyClose failed with error #", GetLastError() );
                                }
                           }
}
```